# Is it possible to have List of Unbound Generics?

Tags: c#

Surprisingly, I don't see this question listed already on stack overflow.

I have an interface, defined as such:

`IDatabaseRepository<in T> where T : DatabaseConfigBase`

I have multiple implementations, such as:

`MongoDatabaseRepository<in MongoDatabaseConfig>`

`MySqlDatabseRepository<in MySqlDatabaseConfig>`

I also have a factory, that returns me the required repository, so I can check the correct database according to configuration at runtime:

```
class RepositoryFactory 
{
    public RepositoryFactory(IEnumerable<IDatabaseRepository> dbImplementations)

    public IEnumerable<IDatabaseRepository<>> Create(string dbName)
}
```

This last class is invalid, because I cannot accept an IEnumerable of just IDatabaseRepository.  The compiler requires that I specify `IDatabaseRepository<T>`, but I do not know what T will be?  I want a list of all my implementations, regardless of their T!

Is there any solution other than boxing and unboxing everything to and from (object)?

Comment: The normal action is to create a non-generic interface within your hierarchy, such as `IDatabaseRepository<T> : IDatabaseRepository`, and then make that your list element. It's imperfect, but it gives you more restriction that just using object.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram However, those are quite often a code smell, particularly if they are empty interfaces (often called marker interfaces) and I would suggest that in this case, they are smelly.

Comment: @DavidG It doesn't have to be empty interfaces. You can have the non-generic interface expose method signatures using `object` type in place of the generic type parameter.

Comment: @alans Yes, but using `object` would be even smellier to me. If a dev working for me wrote code like that, I'd make them rewrite it.

Comment: @davidg - I agree.  If there's no way of doing IEnumerable<IMyGeneric<>>, then I think I need to rethink my architecture.  I agree that boxing and unboxing to object is strong evidence of a code smell, whether its done with an additional base interface, or not.  I am, however, surprised that you can't enumerate across a generic interface for all typed implementations of that interface.

Comment: Even if you could have a list of `IDatabaseRepository<>`, how would you even use it? I'm afraid we don't know enough about your problem domain to suggest a better alternative.

Comment: @DavidG - You know what, I think you're right.  I'm trying to get this coding done in too small time blocks, between too many meetings, I need to stop and rethink this architecture.  Thank you.

Comment: They will always be of type `DatabaseConfigBase`.   If all the methods you need are defined in `DatabaseConfigBase` or overridden in the derived classes you're all set.